# Table Cells lose border in Google Chrome PC

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

The following code, in all browsers - *apart from Google Chrome Latest on the PC* - displays a border on the tbody table cells, as specified in the CSS.

Chrome PC, displays the thead border, but not the TD borders. Why? Is it a bug in Chrome, or in my HTML/CSS?

Heres a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EBBdJ/5/) that replicates it:

```
<table width="505" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Testing</td>
        <td>123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Testing</td>
        <td>456</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>foo</th>
        <th>bar</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

```
table {
width:736px;
border-collapse: collapse;
thead {
    border-top: 2px solid #aaaaaa;
    tr {
        th {
            border: 0;
            padding: 12px 5px;
        }
    }
}
tbody {
    border-top:0;
     tr {
         td {
            padding: 10px 5px;
            border-top: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
         }
     }
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_thead.asp Please see definition and usage, it is invalid to put thead after tbody. (The <thead> tag must be used in the following context: As a child of a <table> element, after any <caption>, and <colgroup> elements, and before any <tbody>, <tfoot>, and <tr> elements)

Comment: Is it really necessary to specify `thead tr th` or `tbody tr td` when `thead th` or `tbody td` is good enough?  Don't let your selectors get longer than they need to be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with putting **tbody** after **thead**.

**HTML**

```
<table width="505" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>foo</th>
            <th>bar</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Testing</td>
            <td>123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Testing</td>
            <td>456</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EBBdJ/6/)

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/thead):

> *thead* - A table element. The thead must appear after any caption or colgroup element, even implicitly defined, but **before** any tbody, tfoot and tr element.

Comment: Meh. Thanks. Should have spotted that. The thead is generated/tweaked by server side code, hence it's odd position.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `border-collapse: collapse` and use `border-top` for `TD` and `border-bottom` for `TABLE`.

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EBBdJ/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
table {
    width:736px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
thead {
    border-top: 2px solid #aaaaaa;
}
th {
    border: 0;
    padding: 12px 5px;
}
tbody {
    border-top:0;
}         
td {
    padding: 10px 5px;
    border-top: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a table using `-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;`, which was hiding border color, so to fix I used `-webkit-backface-visibility:visible;`.